# JavaScript sum of values through object

Tags: javascript, json, object, mapreduce

I'm returning JSON data from an API. I am then using map to create my own object.

The data has multiple objects. Here is an example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "job": [
      {
        "jobNumber": "1",
        "jobTasks": {
          "jobTask": [
            {
              "total": { "amountString": "10.00" }
            },
            {
              "total": { "amountString": "10.00" }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "jobNumber": "2",
        "jobTasks": {
          "jobTask": [
            {
              "total": { "amountString": "20.00" }
            },
            {
              "total": { "amountString": "20.00" }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "jobNumber": "3",
        "jobTasks": {
          "jobTask": [
            {
              "total": { "amountString": "30.00" }
            },
            {
              "total": { "amountString": "30.00" }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As from that returned example, I want to have the following:

**jobNumber: 1: Total 20.
jobNumber: 2: Total 40.
jobNumber: 3: Total 60.**

Here is the code I am using:

```
var array = response.data.map(function(item, array) {

   var sumTaskTotal = item.jobTasks.reduce(function(sumTaskTotal, item, index) {
       if (item !== null && item.total !== null) {
          sumTaskTotal += item.total.amountString;
          return sumTaskTotal;
       }
    }, 0);

    array = response.data.map(item => ({
      jobNumber: item.jobNumber,
      sumTaskTotal: sumTaskTotal,
    }));
}
```

However the sum I am using just keeps summing, so I end up with:

**jobNumber: 1: Total 120. jobNumber: 120: Total 120. jobNumber: 3: Total 120.**

I have tried for loops but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Add the json in post also ..

Comment: Do you want an array of `{ jobNumber: Number, sumTaskTotal: Number }` or a string `jobNumber: 1: Total 20. jobNumber: 2: Total 40. jobNumber: 3: Total 60.`?

Comment: The string is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Not actually sure how you got `jobNumber: 1: Total 120. jobNumber: 120: Total 120. jobNumber: 3: Total 120.`. I tried your code and when you log the array, you'd just get an `array with 3 undefined items`; each iteration in the `map` in your code doesn't return anything that's why the array contains 3 undefined items.

Also, `data` and `jobTasks` are objects. You should use `map` or `reduce` on the `job` and `jobTask` properties.

As for adding the totals, `amountString` is a `string` (obviously), and you should convert it into a number first. Otherwise, the result in your first iteration would be `010.00` since you're concatenating a `string` to a `number`. It's not adding `0` and `10.00`.

The `array = response.data.map...` part in your outer map would just go through all the jobs again. Each iteration in `map` expects an item to be returned. If you don't return anything, `undefined` will the value of that array. So instead of mapping the array again, you could just do this:

```
return {
  jobNumber: item.jobNumber,
  sumTaskTotal,
};
```

That would then result in an array with 3 objects:

```
[{
  jobNumber: '1',
  sumTaskTotal: 20,
}, {
  jobNumber: '2',
  sumTaskTotal: 40,
}, {
  jobNumber: '3',
  sumTaskTotal: 60,
}]
```

But, you can do a `nested reduce` instead:

```
const formatted = response.data.job.reduce((prevString, currentJob) => {
  const total = currentJob.jobTasks.jobTask.reduce((prevTotal, currentJobTask) => {
    return prevTotal + Number(currentJobTask.total.amountString);
  }, 0);

  return `${prevString}jobNumber: ${currentJob.jobNumber}: Total ${total}. `;
}, '');
```

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "job": [{
      "jobNumber": "1",
      "jobTasks": {
        "jobTask": [{
          "total": {
            "amountString": "10.00"
          }
        }, {
          "total": {
            "amountString": "10.00"
          }
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "jobNumber": "2",
      "jobTasks": {
        "jobTask": [{
          "total": {
            "amountString": "20.00"
          }
        }, {
          "total": {
            "amountString": "20.00"
          }
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "jobNumber": "3",
      "jobTasks": {
        "jobTask": [{
          "total": {
            "amountString": "30.00"
          }
        }, {
          "total": {
            "amountString": "30.00"
          }
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
};

const formatted = response.data.job.reduce((prevString, currentJob) => {
 const total = currentJob.jobTasks.jobTask.reduce((prevTotal, currentJobTask) => {
   return prevTotal + Number(currentJobTask.total.amountString);
  }, 0);
  
  return `${prevString}jobNumber: ${currentJob.jobNumber}: Total ${total}. `;
}, '');

console.log(formatted.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use just `forEach` to get your desired string.

```
const data = {
  "data": {
    "job": [
      --
    ]
  }
}

let string = "";

data.data.job.forEach((item) => {
  const sum = item.jobTasks.jobTask.reduce((total, i) => parseFloat(i.total.amountString) + total, 0);
  string += `jobNumber: ${item.jobNumber}: Total ${sum}. `;  
});
console.log(string);
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuzavebipe/edit?js,console)

there will be a unnecessary space after your string. use trim function if necessary.